# Is Ask Ubuntu using the UbuntuBeta font?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, design

To be completely honest, I think the current font family sequence is dictated by the Ubuntu Identity Guidelines. I still think that, right now, it's kind of silly:

```
  font-family: "Ubuntu Beta",
                UbuntuBeta,
                Ubuntu,
               "Bitstream Vera Sans",
               "DejaVu Sans",
                Tahoma,
                sans-serif;
```

Is Ask Ubuntu still using the Ubuntu Beta font and if so, why?

Comment: Posted [by request.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6584/what-is-the-difference-between-the-ubuntu-and-ubuntu-beta-font-is-it-worth-using/6600#6600)

Comment: @NickCraver I think you broke the tag there. ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, Askubuntu.com is still using the Beta font. I'm using the exact same css font-stack as Ubuntu.com. If the official Ubuntu site stops using the Beta font, please let me know. Until then, I want to make sure the styling on this site reflects the official site.

Comment: Yep, thought so. That's why I wasn't going to ask this here :)

Answer (score 4):

The current Design Guidlines are as follows:

> font-family: ‘Ubuntubeta’, ‘Ubuntu’, ‘Bitstream Vera Sans’, ‘DejaVu Sans’, Tahoma, sans-serif;

From the [Ubuntu Web Guidelines](http://design.canonical.com/brand/D.%20Ubuntu%20Web%20Guidelines.pdf)

It would appear Ask Ubuntu is following the appropriate `font-family` line up and fall-backs.

Answer (score 3):

Beacuse the Ubuntu font is still under development, having *Ubuntu Beta* in the CSS before plain *Ubuntu* means that testers of new versions of the font will get the new vesrion they are testing, not the old version.

(Though don't ask me why they don't just release Beta versions with *Ubuntu* as the font name...)

Comment: Fonts have a habit of spreading in the wild.  These get copied, stuck in *~/.fonts* and forgotten about.  Having the  status of the font right there in the title speeds up debugging when testers are looking at the wrong font, avoids issues with embedding and text-reflow, and increases the likelihood that people will actually update and replace their stale broken alpha .ttfs.  More information at: http://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubuntu_Font_Family#Phased%20beta .

Comment: @sladen that is exactly why the Ubuntu font is installed through a PPA so it can be updated - rather than being manually installed and experiencing the problems you mentioned.